# Alternatives to deprecated jp@gc - JSON Format Post Processor

Tags: json, testing, plugins, jmeter, format

I am using JMETER to perform http GET requests to a web application. The response is JSON data and I want to format it properly.

I installed with the Plugins Manager the `jp@gc - JSON Format Post Processor` which works great and does not require any setting. However it is deprecated. I tried to use instead of it the `JSON Extractor` but it seems it is not made for formatting purposes.

Is there an alternative to the deprecated `jp@gc - JSON Format Post Processor` JMeter plugin?

Comment: out of curiosity: why do you need that at all?

Comment: Hi, you mean why do I need a JSON format Processor or why do I need a new one? I need a formatting parser basically to have an idea of the correctness of the result (depending on the number of elements returned and some fields). Actually it works good and I do not strictly need a new one but I am expecting since it is deprecated, an alternative should be exist.

Comment: Formatting is not the part of the test, obviously. It just slows the whole thing down. For correctness, you check the certain points at runtime - and for that assertions it doesn't matter how well-formatted it is. For post-execution clues - you can format it as you need it. In your editor, for instance. Or just by logging all responses, and then format it all by external script. Don't do it at the test runtime though - other than for debugging purposes (for which a deprecated one is totally ok, who cares, after all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to continue using JSON Format Post-Processor - you should be good to go, I don't know why it's marked as deprecated as recently [YAML support was added there](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-json-yaml-plugin-using-yaml-in-jmeter) and now the plugin is compatible with [Jayway Jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) which is used by JMeter JSON components.

---

Alternatively you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) in order to format the JSON response using Groovy [JsonOutput](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html) class , the relevant code would be something like:

```
prev.setResponseData(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))
```